# C++ friend each class in a boost::mpl::vector

Tags: c++, boost

How can I have a class friend each class in a boost::mpl::vector? ie, something that expands to:

```
template <typename mpl_vector>
class A {
    friend class mpl_vector[0];
    friend class mpl_vector[1];
    ...
    friend class mpl_vector[n];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing it with boost preprocessor, as suggested by Andres will work.

I tried it out, and it is not nice and will be inefficient to compile.  It also is limited to working up to the BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE.  If his method works then it is maybe a bit cleaner.

classA.h:

```
#if BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING
friend get_elem<mpl_vector, BOOST_PP_ITERATION()>::type;
#else
#ifndef SOME_INCLUSION_GUARD_H
#define SOME_INCLUSION_GUARD_H

#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/iterate.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/size.hpp>

class Dummy {};
template <int Exists> struct get_elem_i {
    template <typename V, int N> struct get {
        //typedef Dummy type;
        typedef typename boost::mpl::at< V, boost::mpl::int_<N> >::type type;
    };
};
template <> struct get_elem_i<0> {
    template <typename V, int N> struct get {
        typedef Dummy type;
    };
};

template <typename V, int N> struct get_elem {
    typedef typename boost::mpl::size<V>::type size;
    typedef get_elem_i<N < size::value> elem;
    typedef typename elem::get<V, N>::type type;
    //typedef Dummy type;
};

template <typename mpl_vector>
class A {

#define BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1 (3, (0, BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE, "classA.h"))
??=include BOOST_PP_ITERATE()

private:
    int test_;
};

#endif // SOME_INCLUSION_GUARD_H
#endif
```

This file includes itself, so be sure to have the same name as the file in the `BOOST_PP_ITERATION_PARAMS_1` bit.

Additionally this code will also cause the class 'Dummy' to be a friend of 'A'.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use something like Boost.Preprocessor or [Pump](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/PumpManual.md), to specialize your template for MPL vector of different sizes. Or just to specialize it manually.

You have to specialize your template by this way:

```
template< typename mpl_vector, std::size_t size = boost::mpl::size< mpl_vector >::type::value >
class A;

template< typename mpl_vector >
class A< mpl_vector, 0 >
{
};

template< typename mpl_vector >
class A< mpl_vector, 1 >
{
    friend class boost::mpl::at< mpl_vector, boost::mpl::int_< 0 > >::type;
};
```